# PHP add 1 month but take into account of year change

Tags: php, date

I have the following function to pull in comments only from the current month. I need it to not pull any comments from the next month.

I have the next month defined as `$to_date` with a `+1` how can I change this to automatically figure out when it is in the next year ie prevent it from looking in month 13? Thanks

```
Function to only pull comments from a date range of the current month
     $from_date = date('Y-m') . '1 00:00:00';
     $to_date = date('m') . '1 00:00:00'+1;
     $all_comments = Comment::find('all', 
     array(
         'conditions'=>array('response_date_and_time >= ? AND response_date_and_time <= ?', $from_date, $to_date )
     )
);
```

Comment: use the mysql date functions for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strototime can do this for you.  You can use the keyword "now + 1 month" which will take the current date +1 and return the unix timestamp, which the date function will turn into the correct month.  Should return 02

```
$to_date = date('m', strtotime('now + 1 month'));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways. As has already been mentioned, you can use strtotime:

```
$to_date = date('m', strtotime('now + 1 month')) . ' 00:00:00';
```

But I think it also might be a good idea for you to learn about the modulus operator `%`. Basically, the modulus will return the remainder after division (in PHP this is a whole number, in other languages (like JavaScript) it will include any decimal values as well). In this case, that means we have a quick and easy way to make sure the month wraps to never be higher than 12.

```
// get the modulus
$dt = ((date('m')+1)%12);
// bit of a trick. December is the 12th month. 12 % 12 is 0, which is invalid
// so we check to see if the month is 0, and if it is we use 12 instead.
$to_date = ($dt?$dt:12) . ' 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about modulus. Cheers